# WPF DateTime Format

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть TextBox текстовое поле которого биндится к полю типа DateTime. 
Сейчас форматирование заданно следующим образом:

```
Text="{Binding Date, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=\{0:D\},ConverterCulture=ru}"
```

Выводит он соответственно примерно следующее: 12 ноября 2015г

А нужно чтобы он выводил следующее: 12 ноября 2015г (четверг)

Как этого добиться?

Comment: добавте форматирование `(ddd)`

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В результате вышло так:

```
Text="{Binding DateOfProduction, Mode=OneWay,
               StringFormat=\{0:D\} ({0:dddd}), ConverterCulture=ru}"
```

Comment: Пометьте как верный

Comment: Смогу отметить через 2 дня.